# C# send/receive Collections using protobuf-net + sockets example

Tags: c#, communication, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm looking for complete example of how to transfer collections between 2 machines by using protobuf-net serialization and sockets connection. All I succeed to find is separate parts of code and no one of them can't explain to the noob like me how to combine all this stuff. Following the .proto file:

```
using System;
using ProtoBuf;

namespace Proto.Transaction
{    
    [Serializable]
    [ProtoContract]
    public class Transaction
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int Type { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public int AgentID { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public string TransactionName { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(4)]
        public string ScriptName { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(5)]
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(6)]
        public double TransactionLength { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Finally, I have to receive this as Observable Collection and set it as DataSet(in order to save it as XML and present it in DataGrid). I'll appreciate any help and/or links to an appropriate materials in the net.
Regards

Comment: Ultimately, there is nothing different about protobuf-net here. Any example that shows you how to send byte[] messages over a socket would suffice. However, I'm pretty sure there is a sockets project example in the source - will check later (not at a PC)

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 2):

At the **most basic level**, you can look at the example under [QuickStart/3 Sockets.cs](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/QuickStart/3%20Sockets.cs). The key point here is that **if you are working at the raw sockets level**, you will need to add some kind of partitioning between messages (because TCP is just a stream). The sample does this by using the `*WithLengthPrefix` methods.

In many cases, however, you may be able to use a pre-rolled RPC / message-passing implementation that already includes message partitioning; in that case you *do not* need to use the `*WithLengthPrefix` methods (although you are welcome to do so).